# Enumerate over DataTable, filter items, then revert to DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, datatable, ienumerable

I'd like to filter items in my `DataTable` by whether a column value is contained inside a string array by converting it to an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, afterwards I'd like to re-convert it to `DataTable` since that's what my method has to return.

Here's my code so far:

```
string[] ids = /*Gets string array of IDs here*/
DataTable dt = /*Databasecall returning a DataTable here*/
IEnumerable<DataRow> ie = dt.AsEnumerable();
ie = ie.Where<DataRow>(row => ids.Contains(row["id"].ToString()));
/*At this point I've filtered out the entries I don't want, now how do I convert this back to a DataTable? The following does NOT work.*/
ie.CopyToDataTable(dt, System.Data.LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
return dt;
```

Comment: I am assigning it, please check the first parameter.

Comment: well i had got my answer, should have deleted the comment, sorry.

Comment: But _still_ that first parameter is meant to be the _source_ ...i think you need dt to be assigned to the _result_ .. (am i missing smth here?)

Comment: First Parameter is the destination.

Comment: sorry but you are wrong: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx  .. see the _parameters_ section and note that its called _source_

Comment: It's an extension method, of course the first parameter is the source, but the first parameter is also the `IEnumerable`, not the `DataTable`, you will see that the `DataTable` actually is the destination.

Comment: duhh. got it >_< . i appreciate the patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an empty clone of the data table:

```
DataTable newTable = dt.Clone();
```

Then import the rows from the old table that match the filter:

```
foreach(DataRow row in ie)
{
    newTable.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Comment: That's what I resorted to doing now too, I hoped for a more elegant solution which utilizes the original DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to filter the rows *in-place*, that is the filtered rows should be returned in *the same* [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9186hy08.aspx) that was created through the original database query, you should **first clear** the [DataTable.Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx) collection. Then you should **copy the filtered rows to an array** and add them sequentially:

```
ie = ie.Where<DataRow>(row => ids.Contains(row["id"].ToString())).ToArray();
dt.Rows.Clear();

foreach (var row in ie)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

An alternative way to achieve this could be to simply iterate through the rows in the [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9186hy08.aspx) once and delete the ones that should be filtered out:

```
foreach (var row in dt.Rows)
{
    if (ids.Contains(row["id"].ToString()) == false)
    {
        row.Delete();
    }
}

dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Note that if the [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9186hy08.aspx) is part of a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwy42y0e.aspx) that is being used to [update the database](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307587), all modifications made to the [DataTable.Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows.aspx) collection will be reflected in the corresponding database table during an update.

Comment: When I clear my DataTable, my IEnumerable gets cleared too.
When I iterate over each row and delete it inside the ForEach Loop, I will receive an error because I changed a collection during the iteration (logically).

Using for loops or creating a 2nd DataTable surely are options, but I'm looking for something a little less dirty.

Comment: @DennisRöttger Why do you think that creating a new tabel is dirtier than mutating an existing one?

Comment: @DennisRöttger Correct. I modified my example to use the [DataRow.Delete()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete.aspx) method instead, which won't take effect until you call [DataTable.AcceptChanges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.acceptchanges.aspx).

Comment: I think it just feels natural to convert data of an object you want to filter to a type that allows filtering, do your thing and then convert it back to the object the data originally "came from", wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @DennisRöttger I also corrected my first example by copying the sequence of rows to filter to an array.